# read text file as matrix and save it as json file

Tags: json, r, file, matrix

my file without header is a matrix with a multiple vectors in RStudio it seems like that :

```
Y 1 1.53 -0.06 0.58 0.52 0.42 0.16 0.79 NA -0.60 -0.30 -0.78 NA -0.39

B 1 -0.01 -0.30 0.23 0.01 NA NA NA -0.15 0.45 -0.04 0.14 -1.16 -0.14
```

I use Json file to recognize my matrice and NA value but it doesn't recognize all vectors on my matrice this is my r script  :

```
 my_data <- read.table(filename ,sep = "\t" , quote= "", 
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE , header = TRUE)
    my_matrix <- as.matrix(my_data[  ,c(4:176)])
    rownames (my_matrix) <- my_data$UID
    exportJson <- toJSON(my_matrix)
    write(exportJson, "matrix_ID.json")
```

i just get one list and it doesn't recognize vectors.
my matrix_ID.json file :

```
[1, 1.53, -0.06, 0.58, 0.52 ,0.42, 0.16, 0.79, u'NA', -0.60, -0.30 ,-0.78, u'NA',  -0.39, 1, -0.01, -0.30 ,0.23, 0.01, u'NA',u'NA',u'NA', -0.15 , 0.45, -0.04, 0.14 ,-1.16, -0.14]
```

i want to parse file as matrix with vectors and recognize NA value on my python script:

```
Y : 1, 1.53, -0.06, 0.58, 0.52 ,0.42, 0.16, 0.79, 'NA', -0.60, -0.30 ,-0.78, 'NA',  -0.39
B :  1, -0.01, -0.30 ,0.23, 0.01, 'NA','NA','NA', -0.15 , 0.45, -0.04, 0.14 ,-1.16, -0.14
```

How could i do ? Thanks for help

Comment: Can you make your question into a reproducible example, and include all the `library` calls you are using?